# how to stop or pause the drawing on canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-studio-2.3

I'm making face editing app. I want to put a drawing on a face with freehand. I want to be able to stop and pause the drawing on canvas. Here is my code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(testbmp, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    circlePath.reset();
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void onClickEraser() {
    boolean isEraserOn = true;
    if (isEraserOn)
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    else
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

Comment: maybe it will be more clear for the readers of this post if we know what exactly you mean with "Stop and pause". If the user edits the image by himself, so what´s the intention behind to stop the drawing? If you want to restrict the user to draw only a view seconds, a timer or countdowntimer should do the job. If it is after some distance, then calculate the distance the user has made and stop at a fixed one.

Comment: Thanks @Opiatefuchs for your response i just want that when the user complete the drawing on image then user click the button and it would stop the drawing method. and user can use other functionality of the app. hope u understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the onDraw execution. Will execute all the methods inside it.
Your app or your view could implement some mechanism to manage a drawing queue and the onDraw methods will draw from the beginning to the position you decided but this is not the natural way of work the method.